# PHP escaping lat and long coordinates.

Tags: php, json

I would like to pass longitude and latitude values to a json file. The code that I currently have escapes the values and adds quotation marks.

Sample json output`{"votes":["{\"lat\":\"51.426799\",\"lng\":\"-0.3313419999999496\"},{\"lat\":\"52.30897\",\"lng\":\"-1.9409359999999651\"}"]}`

I need to remove the backslashes and the quotation marks. Here is the PHP I am working with:

```
    if (isset($_POST['lat']) && isset($_POST['lng'])) {
        $params = array('lat' => $_POST['lat'], 'lng' => $_POST['lng']);

        $jsonObject = json_encode($params);
        $json = file_get_contents('my_json_data.json');
        if(empty($json)){
            $jsonObject = json_encode(array('votes' => [$jsonObject]));
            file_put_contents('my_json_data.json', $jsonObject);
        }else{
            $json = json_decode($json, true);
            $newJson = $json['votes'][0] . "," . $jsonObject;
            $jsonObject = json_encode(array('votes' => [$newJson]));
            file_put_contents('my_json_data.json', $jsonObject);
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "Noooooooob";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're encoding twice. Try changing

```
$jsonObject = json_encode($params);
```

To simply

```
$jsonObject = $params;
```

To remove the quotation marks, cast the PHP strings:

```
$params = array('lat' => (float)$_POST['lat'], 'lng' => (float)$_POST['lng']);
```

Comment: Thanks it removes the backslashes - how can I remove the double quotes on the lat and long values?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['lat']) && isset($_POST['lng'])) {
    $params = array('lat' => $_POST['lat'], 'lng' => $_POST['lng']);

    $json = file_get_contents('my_json_data.json');
    if(empty($json)){
        $params["votes"] = 1;
        $jsonObject = json_encode(array('votes' => $params));
        file_put_contents('my_json_data.json', $jsonObject);
    }else{
        $json = json_decode($json, true);
        $newJson = $json['votes']++;
        $jsonObject = json_encode($json);
        file_put_contents('my_json_data.json', $jsonObject);
    }
}
else {
    echo "Noooooooob";
}
```

Try to reset my_json_data.json file..

edit1: ok, you are using json_encode twice.. first u encode it to string which makes the backslashes, and then you encode it again..

Comment: The data stills contains doubble quotes and backslashes, `{"votes":["{\"lat\":\"51.5073509\",\"lng\":\"-0.12775829999998223\"},{\"lat\":\"51.5073509\",\"lng\":\"-0.12775829999998223\"}"]}`

Comment: Thanks for the upadte this produces this: '{"votes":[{"lat":"51.5073509","lng":"-0.12775829999998223"}]}' - how can I remove the double quotes form the lat and ling strings?

Answer (score 0):

You encode $params two times.

First: `$jsonObject = json_encode($params);` so $jsonObject contain a json encoded $params (as string)

After you put this string to votes array here:

`$jsonObject = json_encode(array('votes' => [$jsonObject]));`

or here

`$newJson = $json['votes'][0] . "," . $jsonObject;`

after encode it again as a string, not as an array:

`$jsonObject = json_encode(array('votes' => [$newJson]));`

I think do you want do this:

```
if (isset($_POST['lat']) && isset($_POST['lng'])) {
    $params = array('lat' => $_POST['lat'], 'lng' => $_POST['lng']);

    $json = @file_get_contents('my_json_data.json');
    if(empty($json)){
        $jsonObject = json_encode(array('votes' => [$params]));
        file_put_contents('my_json_data.json', $jsonObject);
    }else{
        $json = json_decode($json, true);
        $json['votes'][] = $params;
        file_put_contents('my_json_data.json', json_encode($json));
    }
}
else {
    echo "Noooooooob";
}
```

Comment: This produces this: '{"votes":[{"lat":"51.5073509","lng":"-0.12775829999998223"}]}' - how can I remove the double quotes form the lat and ling strings?